# Good tutorial on grep, sort, unique and tools like that

Tags: command-line

I don't even know how those tools are called together, but i think they make linux a very powerful OS. Do you know any good tutorials to learn those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An old Unix spell book called,Unix Text Processing that is still useful today, even on Ubuntu,
is available here; http://oreilly.com/openbook/utp/ download PDF, open with Evince, read and enjoy!

grep on page 301, uniq on page 323

Text Processing in Linux should also be helpful, http://www.brezeale.com/technical_notes/text_processing.shtml

Comment: The second link seems to be dead - here is a [Wayback Machine snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20170505150900/https://www.brezeale.com/technical_notes/text_processing.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking may fit in "Text processing". This is a quick introduction:

http://xahlee.org/UnixResource_dir/unix_shell_text_processing.html

Comment: The link seems to be dead - here is a [Wayback Machine snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20120110183054/http://xahlee.org/UnixResource_dir/unix_shell_text_processing.html). Looking into [the new domain xahlee.info](https://www.google.com/search?q=unix+shell+text+processing+site:xahlee.info), I did not find something exactly like this - but this is similar: [Linux: Text Processing: grep, cat, awk, uniq](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_shell_text_processing.html).